# Twitter API Basic or Free Plan for Scraping Tweets from Twitter?

Tags: twitter, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2, sttwitterapi, twitter-api-v1

I'm a college student I am currently doing research in NLP, which I need to scrape tweets from Twitter. Does anybody who are experienced with Twitter API, may I know that must I subscribe Basic plan to scrape tweets from Twitter or I can directly use the Free Plan?

I have tried using Twitter API free plan to programmatically scrape tweets using Python and I failed to do so.